# Using map with filter

Tags: swift

I want to iterate over an array of arrays so search for a specific item and return true if exits.

```
var fruits = ["apple", "banana"]
var names = ["ivan", "john", "maria"]
var mainArray = [fruits, names]

// i want to return true if theres a name/fruit that is "john"
func search() -> Bool {
    for object in mainArray {
        if (object.filter { $0 == "john" }).count > 0 {
           return true
        }
    }
    return false
}


search()
```

This works but there a shorter version using .map and avoiding for object in mainArray ?
like mainArray.map.filter... ?

Comment: `contains` is the way to go as @oisdk shows. But its also worth noting that you should write `!blah.isEmpty` rather than `blah.count > 0` – as well as making intent a bit clearer, if `blah` is not random access, `.count` is `O(n)` whereas `.isEmpty` is `O(1)`.

Comment: now that swift is opened sourced, I can verify that the implementation of `.isEmpty` is just  `public var isEmpty: Bool { return count == 0 }` So although `.isEmpty` is the preferred syntax and used as such throughout the stdlib, it does not seem to have a performance gain.

Comment: Like I say in the comment, if `blah` _is not random access_ it wil be more efficient. Arrays are of course random access so there is no difference. But the default implementation of `CollectionType.isEmpty` is `public var isEmpty: Bool {
    return startIndex == endIndex
  }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var fruits = ["apple", "banana"]
var names = ["ivan", "john", "maria"]
var mainArray = [fruits, names]

func search() -> Bool {
  return mainArray.contains { $0.contains("john") }
}
```

Or, in Swift 1:

```
func search() -> Bool {
  return contains(mainArray) {
    inner in contains(inner) {
      $0 == "john"
    }
  }
}
```

As was pointed out by @AirspeedVelocity, you can actually make those closures have shorthand arguments:

```
func search() -> Bool {
  return contains(mainArray) { contains($0) { $0 == "john" } }
}
```

Comment: [[String]] does not have a member contains

Comment: Yeah, the first example is Swift 2. I've updated it with Swift 1.

Comment: You can nest shorthand arg names – so you can write `contains(mainArray) { contains($0) { $0 == "john" } }` if you prefer.

Comment: Ooh, you're right. I'll update it there. I was always unsure about where I could and couldn't use shorthand arguments in Swift 1. Especially with nested closures.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't use map and filter, but why don't you use contains ?

```
func search() -> Bool {
    for object in mainArray {
        if contains(object, "john") {
           return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```